# Office 365 APIs for Javascript Windows 8 Store App Developers

Tags: javascript, office-365

When will the newly released/previewed Office 365 APIs be available for all of the JavaScript Windows 8 Store App Developers?

Answer (score 0):

No official release date yet, other than "coming soon".  Keep checking dev.office.com for more info, or I'm sure the SP Twitterverse will explode when they're out.

Comment: There is no official release date for any of the preview API stuff. What I'm hoping for / EXPECTING is that the JavaScript Libraries will be released, even in preview, hot on the heels of this release. It would be nice for ALL of the Win8 Store App developers to be able to use the new tools, not just a portion of them, as it is now.